# Windows 7 stuck at "setup is starting" during installation from USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation

I am trying to install Windows 7 through USB in my Dell studio 1555 Laptop. Every time it gets stuck at

> setup is starting

I have already disabled all other boot options except USB. There is no floppy drive option.

I have gone through more or less every post related to this problem , but the common solution that is to remove all the USB, Firewire etc. attachments. It does not work in my case as I am installing from USB.

Please help as I have already tried it 5 to 6 times.

---

I created the bootable USB using a video at you tube "how to make USB bootable".
I did not get it with laptop.I make it bootable using Windows 7 iso using diskpart and the process described in that video.Video is correct as my friend installed the Windows 7 using that same video.
It's  almost 15 minutes since screen got stuck.

Comment: How long have you waited? I had a similar issue before. Windows got stuck on several stages of the setup for like 20 minutes. Try waiting more, it might work.

Comment: How did you create the USB stick? Was it one you got with the laptop or did you create it from an .iso? If you made it from an .iso was it using the Windows Live USB/CD download tool?

Comment: Try using a portable hard drive instead of a USB key.  *How* did you transfer the files onto the USB stick?

Comment: Please do not use answers to add more information. [Edit your original question](http://superuser.com/posts/306408/edit) to add additional information. Additionally, if you [log in](http://superuser.com/users/login) then your account will be saved and you will not lose access to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in the past. I basically force shut down (pressing and hold power button).

When I turned the computer back on, it went through the setup process for a first boot normally and didn't get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

"I make it bootable using Windows 7 iso using diskpart and the process described in that video."

Not all newer BIOS seem to recognize disks made via your method. Better to make a bootable drive using Windows Media Creation (MCT), Rufus.ie, or WinSetupFromUSB.